# SignalR Remote connection to RemoteDesktop

Tags: c#, winforms, console, signalr

Simple situation. How to connect to SignalR server app which is in my remote desktop server(Ports enabled) using client which is in my computer. Connection works perfect while in local host, as soon as I put my remote machine IP it gives error 400.

Server side:

```
    namespace SignalRHub
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }

    [HubName("TestHub")]
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        public void DetermineLength(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);

            string newMessage = string.Format(@"{0} has a length of: {1}", message, message.Length);
            Clients.All.ReceiveLength(newMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Client side

```
namespace SignalRClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHubProxy _hub;
            //string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";


            string url = @"http://111.11.11.111:8080";



            var connection = new HubConnection(url);
            _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");

            try
            { 
                connection.Start().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection OK. Connected to: "+url);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }


            _hub.On("ReceiveLength", x => Console.WriteLine(x));

            string line = null;
            while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _hub.Invoke("DetermineLength", line).Wait();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Error it gives:

"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'"

I know there are similar topics but since I am only familiar with C# console and Windows apps only, would be great to found a solution for connection for app to app kind of thing. My RDP server is fully reachable I have databases and other services running there, so the problem is obviously in code. I have changed the IP in post by the way so its not real..
P.S. if I use url = @"http://*8080/" in server side, the compiler gives "HttpListenerException: Access is denied" ...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by opening connection in server side using CMD as administrator and putting:

```
netsh http add urlacl http://*:8080/ user=EVERYONE
```

Also make sure ports are opened in firewall.
.NET application development WebSocket services in ISS has to be enabled too.